# pl sql, how to keep only one row for every time interval per group by

Tags: sql, group-by, row, oracle-sqldeveloper, intervals

Im using Oracle SQL Developer and for the following table:

```
GROUP DATE  
1     2013-01-01  
1     2013-01-02  
1     2013-06-01  
1     2013-06-30  
1     2013-08-01  
2     2013-01-01  
2     2013-01-02  
2     2013-01-03  
2     2013-12-31
```

I want to keep only a row for every 50 days, in each group,
so the resulting table is:

```
GROUP DATE  
1     2013-01-01  
1     2013-06-01  
1     2013-08-01  
2     2013-01-01  
2     2013-12-31
```

So I want to keep every first row of each group, then if there is I want to select
the next one within the group with a DATE 50 days later, and so on till the last row of the group.

thanks

Comment: You need to use `connect by prior`. Try it, it is really simple

Comment: Hello cha, can you show me how to use

Comment: .. how to use connect to prior with my example, thx

Answer (score 0):

As a first step into the right direction you could use this. It is working for your sample data, but is only checking for the first date of each group and then all dates  greater or equal that date + 50 days. Not sure how to implement the check for just one date every 50 days.

```
WITH
    t AS
    (
        SELECT
            1 g,
            '2013-01-01' d
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            1 g,
            '2013-01-02' d
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            1 g,
            '2013-06-01' d
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            1 g,
            '2013-01-30' d
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            1 g,
            '2013-08-01' d
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            2 g,
            '2013-01-01' d
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            2 g,
            '2013-01-02' d
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            2 g,
            '2013-01-03' d
        FROM
            dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            2 g,
            '2013-12-31' d
        FROM
            dual
    )
SELECT
    g,
    to_char(d_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') d
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            g,
            MIN(to_date(d, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) d_date
        FROM
            t
        GROUP BY
            g
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t.g,
    t.d
FROM
    t,
    (
        SELECT
            g,
            MIN(to_date(d, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) d_date
        FROM
            t
        GROUP BY
            g
    )
    t1
WHERE
    to_date(t.d, 'yyyy-mm-dd') >= t1.d_date+50
  and t.g = t1.g
    Order by g, d
  ;
```

Output:

```
"G"                           "D"                           
-----------------------------------------
"1"                           "2013-01-01"                  
"1"                           "2013-06-01"                  
"1"                           "2013-08-01"                  
"2"                           "2013-01-01"                  
"2"                           "2013-12-31"
```